# WPF Window ShowDialog() causing Cannot set Visibility or call Show

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am creating a wpf form which is going to be used for adding/editing data from datagrid. However when I check for `ShowDialog() == true` I am getting the above exception.

The code is taken from a book (Windows Presentation Foundation 4.5 Cookbook).

```
UserWindow usrw = new UserWindow();
usrw.ShowDialog();
if (usrw.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     //do some stuff here;               
}
```

And on the WPF window:

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult = true;
   Close();
}
```

How I can handle this?

===============================

The solution to the problem was simply to remove usrw.ShowDialog(); and it start working as expected

```
UserWindow usrw = new UserWindow();
//usrw.ShowDialog();
if (usrw.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     //do some stuff here;               
}
```

Comment: doesn't show dialog return a DialogResult enumaration ?

Comment: When I clik on WPF form save button it close the window and I got the exception on if (usrw.ShowDialog() == true)

Comment: it seems like you call show , than Close the window , and then after closing you call show again , with the same instance of the window youv'e just Disposed of ..., listen it seems like you just have a redudent line of code , call show only from the if statment , or make an if statment of the result return from ShowDialog.

Comment: You are totally right. Called it directly from if statement and it worked:) thanks

Comment: @eranotzap.  No.  in 4.5 they made it a nullable bool.

Comment: @GarryVass thanks , didn't know that , in what situation does a null value return from ShowDialog ?

Comment: When it was never set to t/f...

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to open your window 2 times with every call to `ShowDialog()`

try

```
UserWindow usrw = new UserWindow();
bool result =(bool)usrw.ShowDialog();
if (result)
{
     //do some stuff here;               
}
```

or

```
UserWindow usrw = new UserWindow();
usrw.ShowDialog();
if ((bool)usrw.DialogResult)
{
    //do some stuff here;               
}
```

keep in mind that `DialogResult` is Nullable. If there is a chance that you are closing the window without setting the DialogResult, check for `null`.

Comment: I've added a solution to the problem, but your solution is also nice